# Shell often exits after sourcing .bashrc file. Caused by infinite loop in Nvm

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, pyenv

### Note

I edited the original post to get rid of red herrings and update for the newest `.bashrc`.

### Post

I have a local Mac (using Zsh) and ssh into a EC2-based linux devbox (using Bash).

When I `source ~/.bashrc` on my linux computer, my shell *often* exits. I say "often" because it's inconsistent. I just tried running the same command twice, and the problem only appeared the second time. **This problem also happens if I source inside a tmux session**, so this isn't an ssh issue. When I add `PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE[0]##*/}:$LINENO+'; set -x` at the top of the `.bashrc` file, I just see a stream of `::.bashrc:126+cdnvm /home/jalvarado` messages. Based on this output, I think the last successfully-executed command is `alias cd='cdnvm'`.

```
::.bashrc:124+'[' -s /home/jalvarado/.nvm/bash_completion ']'
::.bashrc:124+. /home/jalvarado/.nvm/bash_completion
:::bash_completion:5+command -v nvm
:::bash_completion:86+[[ -n '' ]]
:::bash_completion:96+complete -o default -F __nvm nvm
::.bashrc:167+alias cd=cdnvm
::.bashrc:168+cdnvm /home/jalvarado
::.bashrc:126+cdnvm /home/jalvarado
::.bashrc:126+cdnvm /home/jalvarado
::.bashrc:126+cdnvm /home/jalvarado
::.bashrc:126+cdnvm /home/jalvarado
...
::.bashrc:126+cdnvm /home/jalvarado
::.bashrc:126+cdnvm /home/jalvarado
::.bashrc:126+cdnvm /home/jalvarado
::.bashrc:126+cdnvm /home/jalvarado
Connection to devrestricted-jalvarado.ec2.pin220.com closed.
```

Despite this, I have no problem starting a new shell. When I ssh into my devbox or start a new tmux session, I don't see any output. In fact, I no longer see "hello" as part of my `echo "hello"` command in the .bashrc, which I was using to debug earlier until the echo mysteriously disappeared.

I'm at a loss for how to investigate this. Does anyone have suggestions?

Here are the full contents of my `.bashrc` file. Almost all of it was programmatically generated (not by me). The only lines I manually added are the pyenv lines at the bottom and the debugging line at the very top.

```bash
# For debugging
PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE[0]##*/}:$LINENO+'; set -x

# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
cdnvm() {
  cd "$@";
  nvm_path=$(nvm_find_up .nvmrc | tr -d '\n')

  # If there are no .nvmrc file, use the default nvm version
  if [[ ! $nvm_path = *[^[:space:]]* ]]; then

    declare default_version;
    default_version=$(nvm version default);

    # If there is no default version, set it to `node`
    # This will use the latest version on your machine
    if [[ $default_version == "N/A" ]]; then
      nvm alias default node;
      default_version=$(nvm version default);
    fi

    # If the current version is not the default version, set it to use the default version
    if [[ $(nvm current) != "$default_version" ]]; then
      nvm use default;
    fi

    elif [[ -s $nvm_path/.nvmrc && -r $nvm_path/.nvmrc ]]; then
    declare nvm_version
    nvm_version=$(<"$nvm_path"/.nvmrc)

    declare locally_resolved_nvm_version
    # `nvm ls` will check all locally-available versions
    # If there are multiple matching versions, take the latest one
    # Remove the `->` and `*` characters and spaces
    # `locally_resolved_nvm_version` will be `N/A` if no local versions are found
    locally_resolved_nvm_version=$(nvm ls --no-colors "$nvm_version" | tail -1 | tr -d '\->*' | tr -d '[:space:]')

    # If it is not already installed, install it
    # `nvm install` will implicitly use the newly-installed version
    if [[ "$locally_resolved_nvm_version" == "N/A" ]]; then
      nvm install "$nvm_version";
    elif [[ $(nvm current) != "$locally_resolved_nvm_version" ]]; then
      nvm use "$nvm_version";
    fi
  fi
}
alias cd='cdnvm'
cd $PWD

export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"

echo "hello"
```

Comment: You're expected to track down a narrow, specific problem **before** asking a question here.

Comment: To better do so in this case, add `PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE[0]##*/}:$LINENO+'; set -x` at the top of the .bashrc so you can see exactly where it exits. Once you know that, you can make a copy of the file and work on cutting it down to a [mre] -- the shortest possible example that causes the same problem.

Comment: BTW, any chance you might be sourcing your `.bashrc` into a shell that _isn't actually bash_? That would explain `shopt` not being found (`shopt` should _always_ be available in bash; any shell that doesn't have it isn't actually bash). Keep in mind that `sh` and `bash` are two different shells; they don't substitute for each other; the same is true for bash and zsh.

Comment: ...ahh, the clarification that you're using zsh on the Mac explains things. Don't try to use a `.bashrc` for zsh; you should build a separate `.zshrc` instead. PS1 strings built for bash aren't _expected_ to work for zsh in the first place.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I only showed the Mac output to illustrate that it was only happening on my Linux machine. However, I'm only concerned about what's happening on my Linux machine. I tried your debug suggestion and am updating the post.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I posted some of the output. Do you understand what it means? Where can I read about what the output means?

Comment: Ohhh wait. Those are line numbers. I guess this is an infinite loop. It's odd because that block of code was created by nvm. Why would I be the one to suffer this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem shown by the xtrace log is the `cd` inside `cdnvm` just calling `cdnvm` again because of the `alias cd=cdnvm`.

To fix it, change:

```
cdnvm() {
  cd "$@"
```

to

```
cdnvm() {
  builtin cd "$@";
```

...forcing the original/built-in copy of `cd` to be used, bypassing the alias.

Comment: Yup, I just realized that after comparing with the up-to-date nvm README. In fact, it was already fixed https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/pull/2605. Thanks, Charles! I wouldn't have found it without your debug command.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my linux machine had outdated nvm code. [There was an infinite loop issue that NVM fixed last year.](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/pull/2605) I'd recommend taking the most up-to-date version of the code they have.

[image: Part of NVM README that contains the code I had.]

Their solution was similar to @Charles's: use `command cd` instead of just `cd`, which they aliased, creating an infinite loop.